# OleDbDataAdapter leaves out Data from Excel Cells

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbdataadapter, ms-jet-ace

***Update:***

Using the open source ExcelDataReader (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) solved the problem.

---

I'm reading in Data from an .xlsx File like this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties= Excel 12.0;");

cn.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["Sheet1$"]", cn);
da.Fill(ds, "Sheet1$");

cn.Close();
```

And Everything seems to work fine, BUT in two specific rows the adapter just cuts off the last line of one Cell(both affected rows have the same content in that specific Cell).

i.e.:

```
"1 : 0x01 : Text_Example1(sometext)
 2 : 0x02 : Text_Example2(sometext)
 3 : 0x04 : TexT_Example3(sometext)"

becomes

"1 : 0x01 : Text_Example1(sometext)
 2 : 0x02 : Text_Example2(sometext)
 3 :"
```

What is the Problem here and how can i fix it?
To me it seems totally random, because in all the other rows this problem doesn't occur.

edit:
I have already tried it with extended properties HDR = NO/YES and IMEX = 0/1 like suggested on many related Questions, but that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: can u show the screen shot of excel sheet?

Comment: i can't because its confidental data

Comment: normally this issue occurs when the cell format is different

Comment: all the cells have the same format (i.e. just text).
Anyway the File is generated automatically (through IBM DOORS) so i would not have any control over that.

Comment: Check if your excel data has any special characters like escape sequences!

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest an alternative approach, an .xlsx file is an OpenXML file -- a ZIP file containing XML and other metadata.

Microsoft has an OpenXML API that allows you to manipulate such files. That's the "native" way to access the data, and should behave correctly.

There's an open source project called [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home) that aims to make the OpenXML API more developer-friendly.  I haven't used it myself, but have seen it successfully used in existing code.

Comment: I didn't use ClosedXML, but Excel Data Reader (also open source) and it works now.
But thanks anyway for the suggestion